# Comando SQL muito lento

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT funcionario.nome, foto.foto, count(*) total
FROM venda, funcionario, foto
WHERE venda.idfuncionario = funcionario.idfuncionario
  AND funcionario.idfuncionario = foto.idfuncionario
  AND gol = 1
  AND ativo = 1
  AND idsancall IN (5,7,8,42,2,3)
  AND data_venda like '2018-09%'
   OR backlog_data like '2018-09%'
GROUP BY nome,foto
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Estou tentando fazer que ele retorne registro `backlog` caso a `data_venda` não for igual ao mês atual, quando coloco apenas `data_venda like '2018-09%'` funciona, mas quando coloco `data_venda like '2018-09%' OR backlog_data like '2018-09%'` apenas fica carregando sem retornar erros.

Comment: tente incluir alguma imagem na sua pergunta , ou uma explicação detalhada, da estrutura do seu banco

Comment: Por favor, coloque a estrutura da sua tabela, sem isso fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Muito obrigado, excelente resposta!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiramente gostaria de lhe apresentar o [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), basta colocar ele antes de sua query que o MySQL mostra vários dados úteis para descobrir o gargalo de sua query.

*Segundamente*, se você nos mostrar qual é a estrutura do seu banco de dados nossas respostas serão mais precisas e vai ficar mais fácil te ajudar.

Mas vamos lá, vendo a sua query a primeira coisa que notei foi a linha:

```
FROM venda, funcionario, foto
```

Nessa linha você está fazendo um `CROSS JOIN`, que é um [produto cartesiano](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_cartesiano), ou seja, você está cruzando TODAS as linhas das três tabelas. Isso significa que se suas 3 tabelas tem 1.000 linhas, seu resultado terá `1000 * 1000 * 1000`. Isso dá 1.000.000.000 de linhas, e isso que mil linhas pra cada tabela é bem fácil de se ter em produção.

Então o primeiro passo seria usar o [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) correto para sua consulta. Como eu acredito que você quer todas as informações, vou supor que seja o [`INNER JOIN`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx). As condições para o JOIN você já tem na sua cláusula `WHERE`, e eu já adicionaria também o `ativo = 1` no `JOIN`, pois não há porque executar um `JOIN` em um registro que vai ser filtrado depois (poderia ser aplicado no `gol` também, mas sem a estrutura do BD não sei o que é esse campo). Vou supor que o campo `ativo` se refere à tabela `funcionario`. Nossa query ficaria assim:

```
SELECT 
    fu.nome, 
    fo.foto, 
    count(*) as total
FROM venda as v
INNER JOIN funcionario as fu
    ON v.idfuncionario = fu.idfuncionario AND fu.ativo = 1
INNER JOIN foto as fo 
    ON fu.idfuncionario = fo.idfuncionario
```

Outra coisa que eu mudaria seria a comparação de data (supondo que a estrutura seja um `DATE` ou `DATETIME`), consigo pensar em 3 abordagens para isso:

1. A que você já está usando, comparar as datas como strings:

   ```
   data_venda like '2018-09%'
   ```
2. Utilizando as funções [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) e [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month):

   ```
   YEAR(data_venda) = 2018 AND MONTH(data_venda) = 9
   ```
3. Utilizando a função [`EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) e pegando o ano e o mês ao mesmo tempo:

   ```
   EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM data_venda) = 201809
   ```

Dito isso, eu não saberia dizer qual das opções acima é a mais performática, seria necessário pesquisar algum benchmark ou fazer alguns testes para poder afirmar algo.

E a última coisa (**e não menos importante**) seria você ver se suas tabelas têm [índices](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) e analisar se elas precisam de um.

---

Pra finalizar seu código ficaria assim:

```
SELECT 
    fu.nome, 
    fo.foto, 
    count(*) as total
FROM venda as v
INNER JOIN funcionario as fu
    ON v.idfuncionario = fu.idfuncionario AND fu.ativo = 1
INNER JOIN foto as fo 
    ON fu.idfuncionario = fo.idfuncionario
WHERE gol = 1
    AND idsancall IN (5, 7, 8, 42, 2, 3)
    AND (
        EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM data_venda) = 201809
        OR EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM backlog_data = 201809
    )
GROUP BY fu.nome, fo.foto
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: Muito obrigado Gustavo :D

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso pelo que entendi você precisa separa suas condições para consulta com parenteses, separando suas primeiras condições da sua ultima condição que é uma data ou outra.

Coloquei asterisco nos os parenteses que você precisa alterar diga se assim ficou bom.

EX: *(*  *)*

```
SELECT funcionario.nome, foto.foto, count(*) total
FROM venda, funcionario, foto
WHERE *(* venda.idfuncionario = funcionario.idfuncionario AND funcionario.idfuncionario = foto.idfuncionario AND gol = 1 AND ativo = 1 AND idsancall IN (5,7,8,42,2,3) *)* AND *(* data_venda like '2018-09%' OR backlog_data like '2018-09%' *)*
GROUP BY nome,foto
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Isso interfere no desempenho da `query`?

Comment: Na verdade vai corrigir o erro lógico pela ausência de parênteses em seu filtro, quando se usa muitas condições é importante usar parenteses para separar essas condições, principalmente quando no meio da condição você usa AND e OR

Comment: Ok, mas não responde a pergunta. A pergunta é relacionada à desempenho, para deixar sua resposta válida, é necessário responder a pergunta e colocar essa resposta atual como um complemento.

Comment: Com a correção do erro lógico, a QUERY se tornará mais eficiente (rápida) porém claro que o desempenho ainda está ligado ao desempenho da maquina, e volume de dados sendo retornados, mas ficará mais rápido do que está atualmente.

Comment: Não exatamente, a `query` provavelmente precisa de outros ajustes, como índices ou até a retirada do `OR`. Talvez com um `UNION` ele resolva o problema de lentidão.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, boa tarde!

Sabe informar se essas tabelas tem muitos registros? Se sim porque voce não indexa essas colunas. Segundo ponto o like degrada muito performance use algo assim:

```
SELECT funcionario.nome, foto.foto, count(*) total
FROM venda, funcionario, foto
WHERE venda.idfuncionario = funcionario.idfuncionario AND funcionario.idfuncionario = foto.idfuncionario AND gol = 1 
   AND ativo = 1 AND idsancall IN (5,7,8,42,2,3) 
  AND ( (MONTHNAME(data_venda) = 9 and YEAR (data_venda) = 2018)
OR (MONTHNAME(backlog_data ) = 9 and YEAR (backlog_data ) = 2018) ) 
GROUP BY nome,foto
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Alem das mudanças acima não se esqueça dos parenteses que o amigo mencionou, pois vc usa or e isso faz toda a diferença.